# Is it right to use Opencart(ecommerce) as another type of website like (blog, portfolio websites, etc..)?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, opencart

Sorry for my title. I just want to ask simple question. I have a project now and I used Opencart because I am creating an ecommerce type of website. And I really understand how opencart works. Now my question is, I have another project this project is more on displaying company's profile and blog. So much more on posting articles. Now is it right for me to use Opencart for this? What I think is just create a custom functionality for this. And remove all the non related functions.

Do I need to switch to another CMS? Or can I still use Opencart?

If it is not right to use Opencart. I am planning to study other CMS. So my choice are Wordpress or Joomla.

Ok that's all. Thanks.

Comment: There is not a yes / no answer to your question. For sure it would be better and easier to use another cms like Joomla / Wordpress that has more functions ready for article and content management but if you struggle a little bit with opencart you could make it work as a cms for a company website.

Comment: Any *(OpenCart) Pro developer* would say: *Don't use OpenCart as a CMS* (unless you need an e-shop and a CMS at the same time). It would be similar to using e.g. a saw or screwdriver to hit a nail. You can do it but it is always better to pick the right tool for it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your great comment. Ok from now on I will study wordpress or joomla as my CMS framework. Sorry for such a newbie question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking for is probably MijoShop: http://miwisoft.com/joomla-extensions/mijoshop-joomla-shopping-cart

MijoShop is based on OpenCart but runs on Joomla so you get the best of both worlds.